# Is it possible to add Search in User Profile favorites

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search, bookmarks

I probably must be wrong here but the way I use favorites in many application is like a bookmark. The idea is like a "save it for later" kind of thing.

So I have bookmark a lot of questions in the past, and I know in the back of my mind that I was sure that I favorite/bookmarked a solution for something important.

To my surprise there is no way (that I know) how to search from within my favorites. Shouldn't we have a way to search only within the users favorites?

Note: I know I can use google and I now I can search on the top nav but then why favorites if I am not using them? I have 2000 bookmarks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can search through your favorites; just enter this as search query in the search box at the top of the page:

```
search query infavorites:mine
```

Comment: Thanks. But it was duplicated :)

Comment: mine is a very nice addition as opposed to userid